# Как правильно настроить CDN/DNS?

Tags: cloudflare, cdn

есть dns сервер Cloudflare, и имеется два сервера которые расположены на разных странах, вопрос если указать IP двух разных серверов, то в данном случае Cloudflare перенаправит юзера с опр страны на свой сервер?

Answer (score 0):

Да, если вы настроите DNS записи для двух разных серверов и привязываете их к одному доменному имени, то Cloudflare будет перенаправлять пользователя на ближайший к нему сервер, основываясь на местоположении пользователя. Cloudflare использует технологию географического распределения нагрузки (GeoDNS), которая основывается на IP-адресе пользователя, чтобы определить его местоположение и перенаправить его на ближайший сервер. Однако, следует учитывать, что эта технология не всегда точна на 100%, поэтому в некоторых случаях пользователь может быть перенаправлен на сервер, находящийся за пределами его страны.